# How do I hide the rating stars in the product list when there's no rating yet?

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

Currently my Magento store shows 'hollow' 5 star ratings for all products without ratings (which is 99.9% of products as it's a new store).

[image: 'hollow stars']

I would like to only have the star rating appear if a product has received one or more ratings.

I would like this to happen on the search results view, category product list view (same I believe) and also carousel display (such as recommended products at bottom of product details page).

The code which I believe is currently calling the stars into play on the list view is in list.phtml and is as follows:

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()):?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php else:?>
<div class="ratings">
<div class="rating-box">
<div class="rating" style="width:0%"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

BUT perhaps there's a deeper level which needs editing so they don't show on a carousel (eg recommended products) also?

I can't find any advice on this specific need anywhere and would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: An "easy" way would be to find the image file being used and erase the outline of the "hollow" star - this way an image is still loaded but is invisible until the other "filled" stars replace it.

Comment: before those code, you need to put condition and into that you need to check that, Is product has any rating or not.

Comment: I did think of the image replacement @StevenJ, but I think it's using Font awesome. (You couldn't have known that with the above info, sorry.)

Comment: I Post answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that thing using this code.

```
<?php 
$ratobj =Mage::getModel('rating/rating')->getEntitySummary($_product->getId());
$ratings = $ratobj->getSum()/$ratobj->getCount();
if($ratings): ?>
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()):?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php else:?>
<div class="ratings">
<div class="rating-box">
<div class="rating" style="width:0%"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I'll try all supplied solutions soon, when I can get back in and make modifications (some server maintenance means I can not go test it fully yet, sorry... long story ;)
I'll see what works best, and choose an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want display if product have minimum one star then rating will display then try this code:

```
    <?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->load($_product->getId());

    if ($summaryData['rating_summary']):?>
        <div class="ratings">
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I think this code help you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I'll try all supplied solutions soon, when I can get back in and make modifications (some server maintenance means I can not go test it fully yet, sorry... long story ;)
I'll see what works best, and choose an answer. Thanks again!